# Replace 3 characters in a string with 3 new values

Tags: c#, html, regex, replace, html-entities

I would like to replace instances of copyright symbols with their respective html entities. As it is now, the copyright symbols were merely copied directly into the product names, so now, when I send an email with the complete order summary, the copyright symbols are appearing as "?" instead. I need to look for (c), (R), and TM copyright symbols in within a string and replace each one with the proper HTML entity code. However, I am not sure how to do such a String.Replace() (searching for 3 characters and replacing them with 3 new values seems complicated for me)

Here is the code for setting up an email message (right now I am only checking for the (R) symbol):

```
protected void sendEmail()
    {
        Item CurrentItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;
        Item HomeItem = ScHelper.FindAncestor(CurrentItem, "gojoOrderReview");
        if (HomeItem != null)
        {
            TextBox rTxt = (TextBox)FindControl("rEmail");
            TextBox fName = (TextBox)FindControl("yName");
            Literal lit = (Literal)FindControl("emailTbl");
            //string html = lit.Text;

                try
                {
                    //.Value = string.Format("<tr><td style="width:80px;">{0}</td><td style="width:50px;">{1}</td><td style="width:20px;>{2}</td><td style="width:20px;>{3}</td><td style="width:60px;>{4}</td></tr>", SkuItem.Fields["Order Number"].Value, SkuItem.Fields["Description"].Value, qtyAmt);
                    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                    msg.To.Add(rTxt.Text);
                    msg.Subject = "GOJO product order summary";
                    msg.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("donotreply@GOJO.com");
                    msg.Body = "Here is a list of the products your friend, " + fName.Text + ", has selected: ";
                    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                    msg.Body += "<h1></h1>";
                    msg.Body += "<table cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0' border='1px solid black' style='padding: 4px 0 4px 0; border-collapse: collapse; width:750px; text-align: left; font-family: sans-serif;'><tr><th></th><th>Product</th><th>GOJO SKU</th><th>Size</th><th>Case Pack</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>";
                    msg.Body += lit.Text.ToString().Replace("®", "&reg;") +"</table>";



                    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient sc = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("mail.innismaggiore.com");
                    sc.Send(msg);
                }
                catch (Exception EX)
                {
                    GOJOHelper.WriteLog("GOJO Order Review - sendEmail()", EX.ToString());
                }

        }
    }
```

And here is the code for creating the lit variable's text value:

```
lit.Text += string.Format("<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td><td>{3}</td><td>{4}</td><td>{5}</td></tr>",  drow["Thumbnail"], CPNItem["Complete Name"], marketItem.Fields["SKU"].Value, drow["Size"].ToString(), marketItem.Fields["Case Pack"].Value, qtys.ToString());
```

Comment: You can just chain calls to String.Replace.  Regular expressions are going to be more trouble than they're worth for this kind of problem.

Comment: You should not chain `String.Replace` calls because each one will iterate over the original string create a new string.

Comment: Consider using a `StringBuilder` to build body body. Each string **+=** concatenation will produce a new string.

Comment: Yes, true enough, but the performance hit is negligible most of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain the `Replace()` method for every Replace operation.

Try this:

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(lit.Text.ToString());
msg.Body = text.Replace("value1", "replace1").Replace("value2", 
                      "replace2").Replace("value3", "replace3");
```

Comment: You should not chain `String.Replace` calls because each one will iterate over the original string create a new string.

Comment: Consider using a `StringBuilder` to build body body. Each string **+=** concatenation will produce a new string

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi, now it doesn't even compile. You should use the `Append` method.

Comment: @PauloMorgado: no need of `Append()` because msg.Body is not a `StringBuilder` object. just i changed variable name from `msg` to `text` to remove the confusions.

Comment: The point of using the `StringBuilder` was to build the body - all of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to encode this kind of character, you should use a html encoder instead.

In C#, you can use this :

```
string result = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Sample string ©");
```

If you want to replace every character one by one, you can use the code of Sudhakar Tillapudi. His answer is valid, but you are going to do a lot of replace.

The website DotNetPerls has a [good example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/htmlencode-htmldecode) of `HtmlEncode` :

```
using System;
using System.Net;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string a = WebUtility.HtmlEncode("<html><head><title>T</title></head></html>");
        string b = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(a);

        Console.WriteLine("After HtmlEncode: " + a);
        Console.WriteLine("After HtmlDecode: " + b);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
After HtmlEncode:
&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;title&gt;T&lt;/title&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;/html&gt;

After HtmlDecode:
<html><head><title>T</title></head></html>
```